# What type of damage does the Swarm Hunter Art deal?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

In Monster Hunter, there are 5 types of damage: cutting, blunt, shot, elemental, and pure. Which of these does the Swarm deal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swarm's damage type matches the Kinsect in use: cutting for cutting Kinsects, and blunt for blunt Kinsects. Any eventual element is not copied.